# How to get the right message to display?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having problems with displaying the right message for a certain case. Part of my program checks if what the user entered has even or odd digits, and should display a corresponding message for each case. My problem is that I want to display the message "There are no even/odd numbers" if no even/odd numbers were entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;   // Needed for Scanner class
import java.io.*;           // Needed for File I/O classes

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Continue = "yes";
        int num;

        //creates the file name
        File fileWR = new File("outDataFile.txt");
        //creates the file object
        fileWR.createNewFile();
        //file scanner
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileWR, true));

        while (Continue.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer number greater than 0 :");
            num = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
                if (fileWR.exists())
                {
                    validate(num, output);
                }
                else
                {
                    fileWR.createNewFile();
                }

                //option if the user wants to continue
                System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?(yes or no): ");
                Continue = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
        output.close();
    }


    public static void validate(int num, BufferedWriter output) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (num > 0)
        {
            System.out.print("The original numbers are " + num +"\n");
            output.write("\r\nThe original numbers are " + num +"\r\n");
            reverse (num, output);
            even (num, output);
            odd(num, output);
        }
        else if (num <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer");
            num = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Error, please enter a vaid positive number");
            num = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }// end of public static void validate

    public static void reverse(int num, BufferedWriter output) throws IOException {                                                                                                         
        String input = String.valueOf(num);         //must output result within the void method for it to count as a void method
        String result = "";                         //otherwise, you cannot output it in the main method.

        for (int i = (input.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) 
           {
               result = result + input.charAt(i)+' ';
           }
           result = "the number reversed "+ result +"\r\n";
           System.out.print(result);
           output.write(result);
    }// end of public static void reverse

    public static void even(int num, BufferedWriter output) throws IOException {
        String input = String.valueOf(num);
        String result = "";

           for (int i = 0; (i < input.length()); i++) 
           {
               if (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)) % 2 == 0) 
                   result = result + input.charAt(i) + ' ';
               else if (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)) % 2 != 0)
               {
                   result = "There are no even digits";
               }
           }
           result = "the even digits are "+ result +"\r\n";
           System.out.print(result);
           output.write(result);
    }// end of public static void even

    public static void odd(int num, BufferedWriter output) throws IOException {
        String input = String.valueOf(num);
        String result = "";

           for (int i = 0; (i < input.length()); i++) 
           {
               if (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)) % 2 == 1)
               {
                   result = result + input.charAt(i) + ' ';
               }
               else if (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)) % 2 != 1)
               {
                   result = "There are no odd digits";
               }
           }
           result = "the odd digits are "+ result +"\r\n";
           System.out.print(result);
           output.write(result);
           System.out.print("------------------------\n");
           output.write("------------------------\n");

    }// end of public static void odd
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the functions even and odd, you are building up a string of the matching digits in the variable result. You cannot know that there are no matching digits until you have looked at them all. Change the logic in even() to be this:

```
   String result = "";
   for (int i = 0; (i < input.length()); i++) 
   {
       if (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)) % 2 == 0)  {
               result = result + input.charAt(i) + ' ';
       }
   }
   if (result == "") {
       result = "There are no even digits";
   } else {
       result = "the even digits are "+ result +"\r\n";
   }
```